# Grails error "too many redirects" in any browser

Tags: grails, spring-security

In `Grails 3.3.11` application using `Spring security core 3.2.3 and UI 3.1.2 plugins` after the user makes registration for a new account, an email with the `registration code` will be sent to the provided email to complete the registration process, this is the default `Spring security UI` flow, I didn't change anything in it, however, when the user presses the link in the email it supposes to take him to the login page as configured in the `application.groovy`, but I get  `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in all the browsers I tried, I cleaned the browser's cookies as recommended but still getting the same error, any idea from where this error comes and how to fix it.

application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.invalidateHttpSession = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.filterProcessesUrl= '/logoff'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postRegisterUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postResetUrl = '/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.register.postLogoutUrl ='/login/auth'  
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl='/' 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl='/login/auth'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.sessionFixationPrevention.migrate = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.sessionFixationPrevention.alwaysCreateSession = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = [ 'securityContextLogoutHandler']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.clearAuthentication= true
 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/login',  access: ['permitAll']] ]
```

I enabled the `security logs` and found after`verifyRegistration` keeps printing this

```
2021-03-05 13:48:01.643  INFO --- [-nio-443-exec-1] g.p.s.web.filter.DebugFilter             : 

************************************************************

Request received for '/login/auth':

SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@19b10b76]

servletPath:/login/auth
pathInfo:null

Security filter chain: [
  SecurityRequestHolderFilter
  ChannelProcessingFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  MutableLogoutFilter
  GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter
  GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter
  UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Comment: have you tried using /login/* instead of just /login for your permitAll? (;

Comment: Try enabling the security logs to see why is the application redirecting?

Comment: Do you have any interceptors in project?

Comment: If you are running BeAPI API Framework plugin, use the profiler tool to see what functions are being called: https://youtu.be/qGmKnxk1w5k

Comment: @JoshuaMoore tired but still having the same issue

Comment: @RahulMahadik no interceptors

Comment: @Orubel not using that plugin

Comment: @PuneetBehl edited the original post